# How can I declare a tox dependency that cannot build in isolation

Tags: python, tox

I'm using tox to test my package, but one of my dependencies cannot be installed in isolation. It has build-time dependencies, but no pyproject.toml file. One obvious solution is to fork the dependency and add a pyproject.toml, but ideally I wouldn't modify third-party dependencies just to test my code.

Is there a way to install a dependency that has (un-declared) build-time dependencies into a tox test environment?

example tox.ini

```
[tox]
minversion = 3.23.0
envlist = py36
deps = 
    numpy
    cython

[testenv]
deps = madmom==0.16.1
```

Comment: How do you install that dependency in production?

Comment: `pip install numpy cython`
`pip install madmom`
:'(

Answer (score 1):

You could use docker to install all non-pip dependencies and then set the `tox.allowlist_externals` for the binaries you want to use in your `command` arguments. You can combine this with a [docker multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to ensure build time dependencies do not end up in your final docker image.

Or you can use tox [configuration options](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#tox-environment-settings) to modify the installation flow. You could consider modifying the `commands_pre` to do whatever you need before `commands` are run.

E.g.

```
[tox]
allowlist_externals =
    apt-get

[testenv]
commands_pre = 
    apt-get install build-essential
commands =
    pytest
```

You would still need to combine the second approach with `tox.allowlist_externals` for the installation command.

Option 2 is a bit crude. If `numpy` is all you need then ensuring `apt-get install build-essential` is run before running `tox` is probably all you need.

Comment: I don't know that this works. What I need is a `pip install cython` in the environment that's being created to happen before tox installs from deps for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this problem is using the `install_command`:

```
[testenv]
install_command 
= {toxinidir}/my_custom_script.sh
```

Then create the bash file ...

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
pip install undeclared_dependency
pip install ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current workaround:

```
[tox]
minversion = 3.23.0
envlist = py36

[testenv]
deps = 
    numpy
    cython
commands_pre =
    pip install -v --no-build-isolation madmom
...
```

The problem is that it basically circumvents tox's workflow of environment creation before running tests. Instead my workaround tries to install every dependency every time I run tox tests.

Comment: I don't think that's a particularly bad caveat; `tox` will preserve its environment across runs, so these deps (`numpy`, `cython` and `madmom`) will already be present in the environment on subsequent runs, and those install steps will be pretty quick as they won't need to install anything

Comment: I mean, it's not pretty. There's a reason tox builds environments in a separate step. Compared to how long test runs take, doing pip install on already-installed dependencies is quite significant. If I'm doing this on a build server, NBD, but if I'm doing it for local test-driven development, it's not desirable. But sometimes correctness matters more than performance